# Добавить стиль к элементам после получения данных от сервера

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Привет всем.
Столкнулся с проблемой такой.
Пишу сервис используя angular и java. 
В angular есть контроллер в котором запрашиваются данные от сервера после полной загрузки страницы:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    $http({
     method:'GET',
     url:'/getNote'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
     $scope.sourcesInfo = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
     console.log("error");
    });
});
```

После получения данных на странице формируется табличка:

```
<tbody id="serviceNote" >
    <tr name="data" ng-repeat="sourceInfo in sourcesInfo" ns-hover-note click-note>
        <td id="td_1"><a href="http://{{sourceInfo.sourceIp}}">{{sourceInfo.sourceIp}}</a></td>
        <td id="td_2">{{sourceInfo.sourceModel}}</td>
        <td id="td_3" class="tdDescription">{{sourceInfo.sourceDescription}}</td>
        <td id="td_4">{{sourceInfo.ownBy}}</td>
        <td id="td_5">{{sourceInfo.comments}}</td>
        <td id="due-data">{{sourceInfo.dueData}}</td>
        <td id="td-state">{{sourceInfo.state}}</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

и появляется теперь проблема. В табличке есть последнее поле с id="td-state" и на основании того какая там будет запись busy или free вся td должна изменить цвет. Если free - то зеленая, если busy - то красная.

Так вот, в обычном скрипте есть просто проверка типа

```
var selected = document.querySelectorAll("td#td-state");
for (i = 0; i < selected.length; i++){
        if (selected[i].innerHTML == 'busy'){
                $(selected[i]).parent().attr('id','busy-tr');
        } else if (selected[i].innerHTML == 'free'){
                $(selected[i]).parent().attr('id','free-tr');
        }
}
```

И вот проблема заключается в том, что данная проверка запускается до того как будет выполнен get запрос на получение записей, и соответственно выполняется один раз и все.

Помогите понять, что можно использовать из средств angulara чтобы когда появлялась запись - происходила проверка выше? Пробовал ставить директивы - но они тоже запускаются до запроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверка запускается асинхронно, чтобы это исправить нужно ее засунуть в коллбэк функцию. Можно также проверку обернуть в функцию и в колбэке вызывать ее.

Выглядеть это должно примерно так:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    $http({
       method:'GET',
        url:'/getNote'
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.sourcesInfo = response.data;
        isBusy();
    }, function(response) {
        console.log("error");
    });

    // Функция проверки, вызовется когда данные придут с бэка
    function isBusy() {
        var selected = document.querySelectorAll("td#td-state");
        for (i = 0; i < selected.length; i++){
            if (selected[i].innerHTML == 'busy'){
                $(selected[i]).parent().attr('id','busy-tr');
            } else if (selected[i].innerHTML == 'free'){
                $(selected[i]).parent().attr('id','free-tr');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Замечания:**

**1.** *ID селектор должен быть уникальным! В вашем случае можно воспользоваться классами.*

**2.** *Условие, которое написано с помощью нативного js, смешанным с библиотекой jQuery, вполне можно(**и нужно**) писать на AngularJS.*

Например использовать директиву [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) вместо вашей проверки

```
<tbody id="serviceNote" >
    <tr ng-class="sourceInfo.state === 'busy' ? 'busy-tr' : 'free-tr'" name="data" ng-repeat="sourceInfo in sourcesInfo" ns-hover-note click-note>
        ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Не забудьте добавить соответствующие классы со стилями.

Comment: Не так тоже не выходит) Если смотреть через отладчик, то после получения данных - таблица еще не формируется, а метод isBusy() уже начнет свое исполнение. Т.е. элементов на странице нет, а функция их ищет - и ищет один раз.

Comment: @Vorobey.A обновил ответ

Comment: вооооо ng-class помог!) Спасибо Вам большое!)